# Why is cookie's expiration date is 'Session' when using Owin

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, owin

My web application is MVC5. I'm calling an url of IdentityServer4 application to authenticate user when logging in.
Here is the method ConfigureAuth of Startup class in my application

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        JwtSecurityTokenHandler.InboundClaimTypeMap = new Dictionary<string, string>();            

        var authority = LayeredConfiguration.GetValue("HydraInsuranceWeb-UserManagement-Authority");
        var redirectUri = LayeredConfiguration.GetValue("HydraInsuranceWeb-UserManagement-RedirectUri");

        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions {
            AuthenticationType = "Cookies",
            SlidingExpiration = false,
            ExpireTimeSpan = System.TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2),
            CookieName = "MyTestCookie"
        });

        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
        {
            Authority = authority,
            ClientId = AuthConstants.InsuranceWebClientId,
            Scope = "openid profile user.management hydra.eventhistory.api",
            RedirectUri = redirectUri,
            ResponseType = "code id_token",

            SignInAsAuthenticationType = "Cookies",
            UseTokenLifetime = false,

            Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
            {
                SecurityTokenValidated = n =>
                {
                    try
                    {
                        var transformedHydraIdentity = new HydraIdentityBuilder(n.AuthenticationTicket.Identity)
                                .AllowSecurityAdmin()
                                .IncludeRoleProfiles()
                                .IncludeIdToken(n.ProtocolMessage.IdToken)
                                .IncludeStandardClaims()
                                .Build();

                        n.AuthenticationTicket = new Microsoft.Owin.Security.AuthenticationTicket(
                            transformedHydraIdentity,
                            n.AuthenticationTicket.Properties);
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        n.HandleResponse();
                        n.Response.Redirect("/Error/NoAuthorization");

                        DiagnosticService.Writer.AddError("Authentication Error", ex);
                    }

                    return Task.FromResult(0);
                },
            }
        });
    }
```

After logging in, the cookie's expiration is always "Session", not the current time plus 2 minutes.
[image: cookies]

But my expectation is the cookie's expiration is a specific datetime, it should be current time plus 2 minutes. If user doesn't operate in 2 minutes, jump to the login page.

Has anyone known this issue? Please tell me how to investigate or debug to know why cookie's expiration is changed.

And there are 2 cookies: `.AspNet.Cookies` and `MyTestCookie`. Which cookie is used to authenticate user?

Comment: You explicitly set the auth cookie name to `MyTestCookie`, so that is your auth cookie.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set `IsPersistent` to `True` when signing in.

```
AuthenticationManager.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties{ IsPersistent = true, ExpiresUtc = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddMinutes(30)}, userIdentity);
```